# handling exception from python gammu library

Tags: python, exception

I'm using python gammu library for sending sms. Sometimes something is wrong and I would like to handle exception. Descritpion of Exceptions is here: https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/python/exceptions.html#module-gammu.exception

I have a problem with getting and returning errors from such situations. I've printed:

```
print(sys.exc_info())
```

It has result:

```
(<class 'gammu.ERR_UNKNOWN'>, ERR_UNKNOWN({'Text': 'Nieznany błąd.', 'Where': 'SendSMS', 'Code': 27}), <traceback object at 0x740a6cd8>)
```

If i assign:

```
error_obj = sys.exc_info()
```

How can I get from it: Text, Code, and type ERROR(here is ERR_UKNOWN)?
I will grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
cls, exception, _ = sys.exc_info()
text = exception['Text'] # or exception.Text ?
code = exception['Code'] # or exception.Code ?
print(cls, text, code)
```

Also take a look at `traceback` module:

```
import traceback

try:
    1/0
except ArithmeticError as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: When I'm trying to execute your code then there is an error for text = exception['Text']: 'ERR_UNKNOWN' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: It's hard for me to guess how to extract that fields, because I didn't find the definition anywhere. Try `exception.Text` if that won't help then try printing all members `print(vars(exception))`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `args` on the exception to get to the `Text`:

```
print(error_obj.args)
error_obj.args[0]['Text']
```